# EntityFramework Code First The Insert Statement Conflicted With FOREIGN KEY Constraint

Tags: c#, entity-framework, asp.net-core-mvc, code-first

I have read every single question involving code first foreign key constraint errors and talked to a few people about it and I still don't understand the error at all. I don't understand why I see this so often when trying to handle foreign keys in various apps. People try to explain the problem and my eyes glaze over.

I have this in my Person model:

```
[Required(ErrorMessage = "Role required.")]
[Display(Name = "Role")]
[ForeignKey("roles")]
public string RoleId { get; set; }

public virtual IdentityRole roles { get; set; }
```

I am doing this in the AccountController when a new user registers:

```
string roleid = user.Roles.FirstOrDefault().RoleId;
NewUserToolContext ctx = new NewUserToolContext();
Person person = new Person { FirstName = model.FirstName, LastName = model.LastName, Email = model.Email, RoleId = roleid };
ctx.people.Add(person);
ctx.SaveChanges();
```

Why is it that every time I try to use foreign keys I keep getting this same error? Is it just not good to use foreign keys? I have debugged and checked and verified that the correct ID is being passed through to the model property when creating a new "Person".

Here is the full Person Model:

```
public class Person
    {
        [Key]
        public int PersonId { get; set; }

        [Required(ErrorMessage = "First name required.")]
        [Display(Name = "First Name")]
        public string FirstName { get; set; }

        [Required(ErrorMessage = "Last name required.")]
        [Display(Name = "Last Name")]
        public string LastName { get; set; }

        [Required(ErrorMessage = "Email required.")]
        [Display(Name = "Email")]
        public string Email { get; set; }

        [Required(ErrorMessage = "Role required.")]
        [Display(Name = "Role")]
        [ForeignKey("roles")]
        public string RoleId { get; set; }

        public virtual IdentityRole roles { get; set; }
    }
```

Error Message:

> The INSERT statement conflicted with the FOREIGN KEY constraint "FK_dbo.Person_dbo.IdentityRole_RoleId". The conflict occurred in database "NEWUSERTOOL_7c54952102864024ab864e4bab34f694", table "dbo.IdentityRole", column 'Id'.
>   The statement has been terminated.

For further info here is the context for the rest of my app:

```
public class NewUserToolContext : DbContext
{
    public DbSet<Location> locations { get; set; }
    public DbSet<Country> countries { get; set; }
    public DbSet<Department> departments { get; set; }
    public DbSet<NewUser> newusers { get; set; }
    public DbSet<Person> people { get; set; }
    protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
        modelBuilder.Conventions.Remove<PluralizingTableNameConvention>();
        modelBuilder.Conventions.Remove<OneToManyCascadeDeleteConvention>();
        modelBuilder.Entity<IdentityUserLogin>().HasKey<string>(l => l.UserId);
        modelBuilder.Entity<IdentityRole>().HasKey<string>(r => r.Id);
        modelBuilder.Entity<IdentityUserRole>().HasKey(r => new { r.RoleId, r.UserId });
    }
}
```

Comment: 1) What is the ID of the role you are attempting to assign to the user? 2) Does that role ID exist in the IdentityRole table? 3) Use profiler to capture the query sent to the database, examine it in SSMS.  Why is it wrong?

Comment: Can you share the rest of the code for the person model. Have you defined the primary key for the table?

Comment: I already checked all that. The roles exist. It is trying to assign the same role id to the property in the person model. I don't know what SSMS is, or profiler, but when debugging I can see that they're one and the same ID.

Comment: Updated with full person model.

Comment: Have you setup the other side of the foreign key in the Identity Roles table?

public virtual ICollection<Person> People { get; set; }

Comment: No I didn't even know I could do that or that I had access to IdentityRole.

Comment: I have build a rather elaborate corporate security solution on top of Identity and I have not had any issues with it. If you have your code for Identity all configured correctly then you should have no issue. The documentation for Identity is pretty bad so you have to find the few god articles out there and have an architectural thought process.

Comment: I guess I'll pay for help at this point, I don't understand any of this. It should work but it doesn't.

Comment: It sounds like the `RoleID` you're inserting is not one of the valid values in your database's `IdentityRole` table. Can you verify that that value is in the database?  Also, is the `ID` field for `IdentityRole` defined as a variable or a fixed-length string?  (`varchar` or `nvarchar` as opposed to `char` or `nchar`)

Comment: I figured out what is happening but I don't know how to fix it. Apparently I can't use a foreign key to reference the AspNetRoles table that gets created. It wants me to add separate tables in my application's context instead called IdentityRole (see last block of code above) or else it gets an error when trying to migrate. It's trying to reference those tables instead of AspNetRoles. I don't get why or how I link it to the EntityFramework user database or tables.